# add required attribute if input type number is more than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just want to add required attribute on my file submit button if my input type number field is more then one.

I searched on google, And i tried some code but not working, Can anyone guide me in right direction?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="reg"]').change(function () {
    if($("#reg").is('>1')) {
        $('#up').attr('required', true);
    } else {
        $('#up').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Registrations</label>
 <div class="input-group">
 <input required="" type="number" class="form-control" name="reg" id="reg" value="" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="file" name="upload" id="up">
</div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: _"if my input type number field is more then one"_ -- what does this mean?

Comment: @evolutionxbox   my input type number's field value is more then one

Comment: `if($("#reg").val() > 1) {` i guess it should be this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$("#reg").is('>1')` you should use
 `$(this).val() > 1`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="reg"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 1) {
      $('#up').attr('required', true);
    } else {
      $('#up').removeAttr('required');
    }

    console.log($("#up").attr("required"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Registrations</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input required="" type="number" class="form-control" name="reg" id="reg" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="file" name="upload" id="up">
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="reg"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 1) {
      $('#up').attr('required', true);
      alert('Error')
    } else {
      $('#up').removeAttr('required');
      
    }

    console.log($("#up").attr("required"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Registrations</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input required="" type="number" class="form-control" name="reg" id="reg" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="file" name="upload" id="up">
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for the input value:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="reg"]').change(function () {
    if($("#reg").val() > 1) {
        $('#up').attr('required', true);
    } else {
        $('#up').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Registrations</label>
 <div class="input-group">
 <input required="" type="number" class="form-control" name="reg" id="reg" value="" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="file" name="upload" id="up">
</div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#reg").val() > 1` val() gives value of text box that you entered

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="reg"]').change(function () {
    if($("#reg").val() > 1) {
        $('#up').attr('required', true);
    } else {
        $('#up').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Registrations</label>
 <div class="input-group">
 <input required="" type="number" class="form-control" name="reg" id="reg" value="" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="file" name="upload" id="up">
</div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```